# Codeigniter cascading dropdown with data from database

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm need help in making a cascading dropdown that contains data from the database

I found a tutorial about this
and
I've tried this

Controller:

```
function ajax_call() {
    if(!empty($_POST['table'])){
        if ($_POST) {
            $table = $_POST['table'];
            $arrYear = $this->my_model->get_categories($table);
            foreach ($arrYear as $years) {
                $arrFinal[$years->category2 = $years->category2;
            }
            echo "<p>2nd Category:<br>";
            echo form_dropdown('year',$arrFinal);
            echo "</p><br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>2nd Category:<br>";
            echo form_dropdown('year','');
            echo "</p><br>";
        }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
$options = array(
      '' => 'Select',
      'category_one' => 'Category 1',
      'category_two' => 'Category 2',
     );



    echo form_error('table');
    echo "<p>Category:<br> ";
    echo form_dropdown('table', $options, $this->input->post('table'), 'id="table"');
    echo "</p><br>";
```

Script inside my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#table').change(function(){
       var selTable = $(this).val(); // selected name from dropdown #table
       $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_call",  // or "resources/ajax_call" - url to fetch the next dropdown
        async: false,
        type: "POST",     // post
        data: "table="+selTable,  // variable send
        dataType: "html",    // return type
        success: function(data) {  // callback function
         $('#year').html(data);
        }
       })
      });
     });
    </script>
```

My Model:

```
function get_categories($table) {
         $this->db->select('category2')->from($table);
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result();
        }
```

My only problem with this is that the 2nd dropdown isn't visible on the page when loaded, and it would only appear when I select on the 1st dropdown.

How can i make set it to appear on the page without selecting on the 1st dropdown?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I couldn't figure out how to do what i wanted. So instead i searched around the deep parts of the internet and found this little tutorial that was actually what i needed.

http://supundharmarathne.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/simple-ajax-drop-down-filtering-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the ajax call to populate your table is only being triggered after the table changes `$('#table').change(function(){...})`. Try populating the table without waiting for such change; maybe inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: how do i achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

you added a completely obsolete `if ($_POST)` to your code. You are already checking if a variable in $_POST exists, hence it can never be empty after that. That caused your ELSE statement to relate to the second IF, not the first.

```
function ajax_call() {
    if(!empty($_POST['table'])){
        $table = $_POST['table'];
        $arrYear = $this->my_model->get_categories($table);
        foreach ($arrYear as $years) {
            $arrFinal[$years->category2 = $years->category2;
        }
        echo "<p>2nd Category:<br>";
        echo form_dropdown('year',$arrFinal);
        echo "</p><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>2nd Category:<br>";
        echo form_dropdown('year','');
        echo "</p><br>";
    }
}
```

and that is why you should **always** indent your code correctly.

Comment: Hi sir thank you for the reply, I tried your code but no it's causing a Php error when i choose an option with an empty value

Comment: then modify the script to handle those. If you are working with PHP, i can only assume you **at least** did a couple of tutorials before trying this stuff out.

Comment: better if you show how u use the drop down in ur views

Comment: @danielad or... just go to https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html and look at the well written explanation and examples of `form_dropdown()` (that is indeed the codeigniter documentation)